# Hide vertical overflow on dynamically sized object in CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Imagine I have two columns. The left column is text. The right column is an image which is very tall. It's a map, but just a picture: not a Google map.

I want to

a) crop the image to the height of the text (which can change dynamically)

b) vertically center the image (center of image is in the center of the container)

In other words, I want a map which can change its vertical height based on the dynamically changing stuff in another column.

If it helps, I am using Bootstrap 4 for layout.

I greatly prefer a CSS solution to a Javascript solution.

I prefer to use an image tag to a background because my map is generated with the react-static-google-map package. But I guess it isn't rocket science to switch to a hand-built URL and a background-image if necessary.

Comment: First of all , We can't sit here and imagine , So it would be great if you could show us an image of what you are tying to do or even post the code of what you have done so far. And it is also not a great idea to increase the size of the image according the increase in the the size paragraph because the image will start to stretch and it will lose its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using a background image, it's easy. Here's an example of how it could be done:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.text, .image {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam orci sapien, convallis vel suscipit nec, scelerisque ut purus. Phasellus pharetra aliquam auctor. Fusce pharetra nibh at accumsan convallis. Aenean et dignissim ligula. In tempus lorem odio, non ornare nulla posuere non. Duis nunc magna, egestas ac tempor lacinia, auctor vitae nisi. Nulla accumsan egestas nisi eget scelerisque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent porttitor pellentesque justo sit amet eleifend. Nam ut mauris eget arcu accumsan vestibulum. Aliquam lorem risus, sollicitudin in enim ac, tempus efficitur nunc. Vestibulum ullamcorper vel nisi eu ornare. Vivamus non enim urna. Donec vel arcu eget lectus dapibus lacinia non id metus. Etiam id mi urna. Pellentesque vulputate finibus posuere. Nunc pulvinar at leo nec condimentum. Quisque consequat velit auctor, pharetra libero vel, hendrerit ex. Phasellus luctus volutpat suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer finibus turpis eget risus pellentesque, id hendrerit ligula condimentum. Morbi eget laoreet mi, et imperdiet diam. Suspendisse ac mi mattis, posuere velit nec, mollis dui. Praesent vitae iaculis ex. Integer in ligula arcu. Curabitur sed purus gravida, mattis sem vitae, tempor nibh. Duis sollicitudin lacus sapien, vitae varius massa aliquam quis.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2014/1-earth.jpg')">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I inlined the style for the background-image because I thought it would help if your image URL's are dynamically created.

Comment: That's cool. I need to add background-position but I guess that solves it.